# Unable to set focus on pop up

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

[![enter image description here][1]][1]**HTML code is shown in Screenshot** [![enter image description here][2]][2]

**I tried with Action class**

`WebElement element =  InspectationOrder.wd.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='qx-window']"));
 Actions actions = new Actions(InspectationOrder.wd);
 actions.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();`

but found `"java.lang.NullPointerException"` while i tried to move focus.
but same action code works for other area in application

Also tried with
`for (String popup : wd.getWindowHandles())`
`{`
`wd.switchTo().window(popup);`
`}`

but not working  :( 
May be issue with z-index but  m don't have more idea about the same .

Comment: what do you mean by popup? is it a modal window or when will the popup appears?

Comment: Nope it is a pop up created by javascript that's why switchTo.window() is not working

Comment: if it's a javascript alert,then you need to use `driver.switchTo().alert()`.

Comment: but this pop up contain many web element in which I have to pass value. So with switchTo().aleart() I think we can not ... do that

Comment: can you provide the screenshot of the popup. i just want to have a look at how the popup looks.

Comment: I have Added the screen shot ..

Comment: it's not a javascript popup.its HTML generated.

Comment: What do you actually need to do on the window? You don't necessarily have to "switch to" or "focus" on it since it's a part of the same window. Capture one of the elements within and you should be able to interact with it just like you normally would

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium latest version(Selenium 3 with GeckDriver ) automatically handles set focus.
Previously I am using selenium 2 in which we have to setfocus on new element.But in selenium 3 with GecoDriver we have no need to worry about small popups.
In my whole automation script selenium 3 handles setfocus[ Not fully but at basic level ]  for me and works form me.

Use full links.
[LINK-1](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/how-to-use-geckodriver/)
[[LINK-2]](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/launching-firefox-browser-with-geckodriver-selenium-3)
-Thanks
Dhaval

Answer (score 0):

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {

            boolean bool = (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor)d).executeScript("return $('.modal').is(':visible') ");

            return bool;
        }
    });
```

Your Dialog is actually an div in an upper layer. This codes waits up to 10 seconds until the dialog is created and show completely. Inside JavaScript is used to select the dialog and check weather is visible or not. (display: none). The result is returned. If the result is false your test will stop.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try adding an id to the div and use the below code?

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id(id)));

driver.findElement(By.id(id inside popup));
```

Comment: If we can do with ID then definitely we should do with class as well

Comment: Am not an expert in this, so can you please try it with class?`driver.findElement(By.className("element class"))`